# How to check a class has a child class

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function A(){

$('input[name="A[]"]').each(function() { 

 alert($(this).val());

});
return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form onsubmit="return A()">
<div class="row JRow">

<div class="BtnSet">

<div class="Child">
<input type="text" name="A[]"></input>
<input type="text" name="A[]"></input>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code... What I need to know is that the class belongs to these textboxes is "Child" and it belongs to class "row JRow". And y is the alert I have put is not working?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: `if($(".ChildOfABC").parent().hasClass('ABC')){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very hard to tell from your question exactly what you're looking for, so a few options for you:

Assuming you already have a jQuery object for the `.ChildOfABC` element in a variable called `obj`, then:

```
if (obj.parents(".ABC")[0]) {
    // Yes, it's inside one
}
```

`parents` looks through the element's ancestry (parent, grandparent, etc., up through to the document element) for elements matching the given selector and returns a set of them. The `[0]` at the end tells us whether the set has at least one entry in it.

So for instance, if you want to check from a click on any `.ChildOfABC` element, then:

```
$(".ChildOfABC").click(function() {
    if ($(this).parents(".ABC")[0]) {
        // Yes, it's inside one
    }
});
```

If you want to find out if **each** element with `ChildOfABC` is inside an `ABC`, then:

```
var children = $(".ChildOfABC");
var count;
children.each(function() {
    if ($(this).parents(".ABC")[0]) {
        ++count;
    }
});
if (count === children.length) {
    // Yes, each one is
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/TkmRW/4/ This is where my actual code is.. Once I click on submit button after creating child text boxes too... I need to check whether the "row JsRow" has a "Child" Class

Comment: @Hiruni: To improve your question, use the "edit" link and paste the relevant code *in the question itself*. A fiddle is a nice *addition*, but it's just an addition. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question It's also important to make the smallest example you can, a [small, self-contained example](http://sscce.org). I just glanced at that fiddle, and there's no way someone's going to wade through all of that code to figure out what you're talking about. The above should point you the right way.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('.ChildOfABC').parent('div.ABC').length) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code `$('.ABC').find('.ChildOfABC')`

Comment: This is not the reliable way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(".ChildOfABC").parent('div').hasClass('ABC'))
    {
        alert('yes');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('no');
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(".ChildOfABC").parent(".ABC").length > 0) { }
```